# using new keyword in callback causes "TypeError: object is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have a call:

```
var serve = function(teacher, callback) {

    RE.createFakeMemberData(function(err, avgMember) {

          //omitted

     });
};
```

inside the `createFakeMemberData`,   if I try to instantiate a mongoose model:

`var statistic = new Statistic();`

I get the error with the stack trace:

```
D:\Orkun\workspace\teb\tebesir-repo\scripts\engines\ResetEngine.js:61
    var statistic = new Statistic();
                    ^
TypeError: object is not a function
    at Object.createFakeMemberData (D:\Orkun\workspace\teb\tebesir-repo\scripts\engines\ResetEngine.js:61:21)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (D:\Orkun\workspace\teb\tebesir-repo\scripts\servlets\graph\ServeSpider-Teacher.js:29:20)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (D:\Orkun\workspace\teb\tebesir-repo\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mpromise\lib\promise.js:177:8)
    at Promise.emit (events.js:95:17)
```

I think the `'this'` is going out of scope or sth. I have also tried using `bind`..

```
RE.createFakeMemberData(function(err, avgMember) {

              //omitted

         }).bind(this);
```

no joy..

EDIT: statistic

```
// external libs that are going to be used
var bunyan = require('bunyan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var _ = require('underscore');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// models that are going to be used
var Subject = require('../../scripts/models/Subject');
var CF = require('../../scripts/utilities/CommonFunctions');
var ResetEngine = require('../engines/ResetEngine');
var MetricEngine = require('../engines/MetricEngine');
var Constants = require('../../scripts/utilities/Constants');

var log = bunyan.createLogger({src: true, name: 'logStatistics'});

var Statistic = new Schema(
{
   solved_tot: {type: Number, default : 0}, // number
   score_tot: {type: Number, default : 0}, // score
   time_tot: {type: Number, default : 0}, // time

   // statistics for all the subjects available to the client
   stats: [{
        stat_id: { type: String, required: true},
        stat_name: { type: String, required: true},
        stat_solved: { type: Number, default : 0},
        stat_score: { type: Number, default : 0},
        stat_time: { type: Number, default : 0}
   }]

}, { strict: true });

// !param new_score the book that has been bought as Book
// !param new_time of the user which makes the buy as String
// !param test_solved the book that has been bought as Book
// !desc should be async for extra performance opt
Statistic.methods.updateStatisticsFromTest = function(test_solved, new_time, new_score, callback) {

    for (var i = 0; i < test_solved.subjects.length; i++) {
        for (var k = 0; k < this.stats.length; ++k) {

            if (test_solved.subjects[i].subject_name == this.stats[k].stat_name) {

                // set the current variables
                var current_score = this.stats[k].stat_score;
                var current_time = this.stats[k].stat_time;
                var current_solved = this.stats[k].stat_solved;

                // calculate and update three indexes
                this.stats[k].stat_score = (((current_score * current_solved) + new_score) / (current_solved + 1)).toFixed(5);
                this.stats[k].stat_time = (((current_time * current_solved) + new_time) / (current_solved + 1)).toFixed(5);
                this.stats[k].stat_solved++;

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // calculate the average total time
    this.time_tot = (((this.time_tot * this.solved_tot) + new_time) / (this.solved_tot + 1)).toFixed(5);

    // calculate the average score
    this.score_tot = (((this.score_tot * this.solved_tot) + new_score) / (this.solved_tot + 1)).toFixed(5);

    // increase the number of tests solved
    this.solved_tot++;

    // save the new user stat
    this.save(function(err) {
        if (CF.errorCheck(err, Constants.DB_ERROR, 'save Statistic')) return callback(err);
        return callback(null, this);
    });
};

// !brief creates an empty subject statistics object for a new user
// !param subjectList (Array<Subject>) list of subjects that will be included to the statistics
// !callback function that will be called when the database query ends
Statistic.methods.createStatistics = function(subjectList) {

    // initialize and add all the subjects to the statistics object
    this.stats = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < subjectList.length; i++) {
        this.stats.push({'stat_id': subjectList[i].id.toString(), 'stat_name' : subjectList[i].name});
    }
};

// !brief aggregates the subject statistics on a single topic statistics
// !param subjectStatisticsObjectList ( Array <Statistic> ) subject statistics to be aggregated
Statistic.methods.aggregateStatistic = function(statisticsObjectList) {

    ResetEngine.resetStatistic(this);
    for (var i = 0; i < statisticsObjectList.length; i++) {

        this.solved_tot += statisticsObjectList[i].solved_tot;
        this.time_tot += statisticsObjectList[i].time_tot;
        this.score_tot += statisticsObjectList[i].score_tot * statisticsObjectList[i].solved_tot;

        for (var k = 0; k < statisticsObjectList[i].stats.length; k++) {

            this.stats[k].stat_solved += statisticsObjectList[i].stats[k].stat_solved;
            this.stats[k].stat_score += statisticsObjectList[i].stats[k].stat_score / statisticsObjectList.length;
            this.stats[k].stat_time += statisticsObjectList[i].stats[k].stat_time;
            this.stats[k].subject_watch += statisticsObjectList[i].stats[k].subject_watch;
        }
    }

    this.score_tot = this.score_tot / statisticsObjectList.length;
    ResetEngine.roundStatistic(this);
};

// !brief gets the topic statistics in the this object which belong to a subject
// !param theSubject ( Subject ) subject that we are going to search for
// !param topicList ( Array<Topic> ) topic lists that is going to be searched
// !return (Array<Topic>) test that are found by the function
Statistic.methods.getTopicStatBlobBySubject = function(subjectObject, topicList) {

    var TopicStatisticsOfSubject = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < topicList.length; i++) {
        if (topicList[i].subject === subjectObject._id.toString()) {
            for (var k = 0; k < this.stats.length; k++) {
                if (this.stats[k].stat_id === topicList[i]._id.toString()) {
                    TopicStatisticsOfSubject.push(this.stats[k]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return TopicStatisticsOfSubject;
};

// !brief find the blob that belongs to the given subject or topic name
// !param statName ( String ) the name of the subject or topic that blob will be found
// !return subjectBlob or topicBlob (Statistic.stats)
Statistic.methods.getStatBlob = function(statName) {

    for (var i = 0; i < this.stats.length; i++) {
        if (this.stats[i].stat_name === statName) {
            return this.stats[i];
        }
    }
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('Statistic' , Statistic);
```

Comment: Can you show your implementation of `Statistic`?

Comment: sure thing. edited the question. elsewhere it s working ok tho.

Comment: Well the `ResetEngine.js` does not seem to import the `Statistic`, does it?

Comment: So I guess you did: `var Statistic = require('statistic.js')` or something like this?

Comment: yes, the ResetEngine.js imports Statistic, i ve checked the path

Comment: Can you show how did you write require statement? Which variable did you assign to `require`?